# Oled Display doesn't work properly

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, python, i2c

Im using my Raspberry Pi zero W For an project with an Oled display and i can't get it to work properly

I Installed [Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306) and tried the examples. It didn't work and i tried an other [example](https://github.com/xxlukas42/RPI_SSD1306) but doesn't seem to work properly too.

edit: found out that i used wrong drivers. Having a SH1106 used SSD*** but can't find any library.
[image: This is my Oled display problem]

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours.  Are you sure the screen dimensions assumed by the software are correct?

Comment: Please add more information such as the model number and version of raspbian you are using. Also please ensure you ran the `setup.py` script.

Comment: I ran the setup.py correctly. Everything works as it should but i have the wrong model (I have SH1106) and for my model i can't find the right python library/driver.
The dimensions are correct.